# insert image into sqlite and retrieve image into the activity

Tags: android, image-processing, android-sqlite

I have got the errors like this when run the above code. Please help me..

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.kalya.farmers1, PID: 32178
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kalya.farmers1/com.example.kalya.farmers1.Harvestitems}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:360)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                      at com.example.kalya.farmers1.DataBaseHandler.getAllContacts(DataBaseHandler.java:97)
                      at com.example.kalya.farmers1.Harvestitems.onCreate(Harvestitems.java:43)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6119)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32178 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1` seems that the error is that you are trying to change the database version from 2 to 1. Try to reset the database version to 2 or maybe if you had made some modifications try to set the version to 3.
Maybe will be helpful if you can post some code too.